# Troubles installing PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-sip

I'm following [this](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/BuildPyQt4Windows) guide.

- Python is at C:\Python31
- PyQt4 is at C:\Python31\pyqt
- sip is at C:\Python31\sip
- Qt is at C:\Qt\4.6.0

I followed the instructions on that guide, but when I tried to test it (`from PyQt4.Qt install *`), it said the module didn't exist. I checked all the files that guide said should exist, and none of them existed.

What should I do?

Oh:

sip installed fine. `from sip import *` didn't yield errors, `print(SIP_VERSION_STR)` output `4.10-snapshot-20091204`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is pre-built version already, why you still need to build yourself?

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py3.1-gpl-4.6.2-2.exe

Comment: Yeah, Googled "install pyqt" after I posted this and saw that. It installed in <45 seconds. Oh well. -.-